# How to validate the timezone

Tags: go, timezone

I need to validate the timezone value that I have been given and that too i want to parse it in a particular date format and time zone should be "-1300 to 1400" (+/-HHMM).

I have tried with some, but I'm not able to get validate the time zone.
If timezone = "`-1260`"(it's a invalid value) , then it should print "`Invalid time zone`" but its not behaving like that.

Here's the code I've tried - https://play.golang.org/p/kbTsQAW-f-_r

```golang
    var validTZ = regexp.MustCompile(`[+-][0-9]{4}$`)
    tz:= "-1260"
    tzInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(tz)
    t1 := time.Now().UTC()
    formattedDate := t1.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000")
    formattedDate += tz
    _,err:=time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-0700",formattedDate)
    if !validTZ.MatchString(tz) || (tzInt >= -1300 && tzInt <= 1400) || err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Invalid time zone")
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code *in the body of the question*, and the *specific problem* you're having - "i,m not able to get validate the time zone" in what way? What happens?

Comment: and what you expect for your `2006-01-02T15:04:05.000` as result? i not really understand

Comment: If time zone = "-1260" , it is invalid timezone value , so it should print "Invalid time zone value" , but it is not behaving like that.

Comment: why don't you make the `regex` more specific? I don't see much help from go's date/time parser... [example](https://play.golang.org/p/d6ueAcZqeV_2)

Comment: yeah , `^[+-]([0-9]{2})([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})$` , I used this and its solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that tz (1260) is `tzInt >= -1300 && tzInt <= 1400`

But your code is:

```
!(tzInt >= -1300 && tzInt <= 1400)
```

The ! negates the condition, making it `tzInt < -1300 || tzInt > 1400`: that is why `"Invalid time zone"` is not displayed.

As commented by the OP, you can also print that error based on a more precise regex:

```
^[+-]([0-9]{2})([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})$
```

That will prevent any `xx6y`  value.

Comment: Its in HHMM format , in that format , MM cant be 60.

Comment: @venu OK, but my point was: as long as you test `tzInt >= -1300 && tzInt <= 1400` with a `!` in front of it, you will never print `"Invalid time zone"`.

Comment: @venu But if you modify your question, which was "it should print "Invalid time zone" but its not behaving like that.", it will start working: it will print   "Invalid time zone", so I have answered your original question, have I not?

Comment: @venu OK. I have edited the answer to include your regex, for more visibility.